# How to use "Come on in"

Tags: american-english

I'm wondering if we can use come on in whenever asking someone to go inside or come inside.

One of my students's mom is American. 
When she dropped off her kid, I heard she said "come on in honey"

I thought we can only use come on in when someone is outside the place or builing.

But she was outside the building even though we all were close to the door of the classroom.

Comment: Neither ‘really’ works if she’s outside, but if she was closer to the classroom than her child, it would be more natural to say *come* than *go*.

Comment: You really need to read Fillmore's famous paper ["May  We Come In?"](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/1-MayWeComeIn.pdf)